# Disabling gnome on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

There are a lot of posts on how to stop gnome desktop in ubuntu. However, on 17.10, I am not able to do that!

As you can see there is no service named `lightdm`. Also, `gdm` has no effect.

```
mahmood@orca2:~$ sudo service lightdm stop
Failed to stop lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not loaded.
mahmood@orca2:~$ sudo service gdm stop
mahmood@orca2:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

I also tried to edit the grub option by removing `quiet splash $vt_handoff` and insert `single`. Still I see gnome desktop!

Any idea?

Comment: gdm has been replaced by gdm3 in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I tried that. Has no effect. I am still in the gnome and typing this in firefox!

Comment: You do realize that Ubuntu 17.10 is EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/?p=8396)  You should upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (very soon 'artful' will disappear from `archive.ubuntu.com` as it'll be moved to `old-release.ubuntu.com`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stopping [gdm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/gdm.8.html) service you could try the `kill` command with PID to kill [gdm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/gdm.8.html).

To get the PID you can use [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/htop.1.html) or top. With PID from this command output use [kill command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/kill.1.html) in a root shell:

```
$ kill -9  XXX <-- replace xxx with PID from the htop
```

If this doesn’t work you can also try

[pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) dm -l

sudo kill  XXX <-- replace XXX with PID